# How to perform bulk insertion in SQL Server from dat file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

My input data in `.dat` file looks like this:

```
 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6 
11|22|33|44|55|66
```

up to 300 000 rows

Dat file contains 6 columns I need to add one default column and perform bulk insertion into SQL Server

How can I do it?

Comment: Please use **internationally know** units of measure - thousands, millions, billions etc.

Comment: you can google for lakhs !! :)

Comment: i can able to insert those 3 lakhs rows into SQL Server using bulk insert.
But my default column is declared as last column.It leads 2nd row inserted as last column of the first row

Comment: @Mahendran, did you look into my answer?  And is this comment is on my answer?  And please ask you question with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding sample execution code for your problem

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow_data (
    no VARCHAR(50)
    ,Name VARCHAR(50)
    ,id VARCHAR(50)
    ,state VARCHAR(50)
    ,address VARCHAR(50)
    ,testdate DATETIME2(3)
);

SELECT  sd.no
        ,sd.Name
        ,sd.id
        ,sd.state
        ,sd.address
        INTO #stack_data
        from stackoverflow_data sd
        WHERE sd.no = 0

BULK INSERT #stack_data FROM '\\test\others\input.dat' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000)

insert INTO stackoverflow_data (no, Name, id, state, address, testdate)
    SELECT  sd.no
            ,sd.Name
            ,sd.id
            ,sd.state
            ,sd.address 
            ,'10-Dec-2014'
            FROM #stack_data sd
```

Comment: Can I bulk insert directly target stackoverflow_data? Why do I meed the temp table #stack_data?

Answer (score 0):

Process your file and add the data into temp table (`#temp`) with same date as in your file. And then insert into your original table from `#temp` table with default value for default column.

```
DECLARE @BulkInsertSql AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT
    column1
    ,column2 INTO #BulkInsertTempTable
FROM OriginalTable
WHERE OriginalTable.id = 0; -- this condition is required to carry forward any identity columns
```

and then bulk insert as

```
    EXEC ('BULK INSERT #BulkInsertTempTable FROM ''' + @FileToProcess +
  ''' WITH (MAXERRORS = 0,FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',FIRSTROW=2);')
```

then insert into your original table from #temp table

```
  SET @BulkInsertSql =
    'INSERT INTO OriginalTable
       (column1,
        column2,
        defaultcolumn3
            )  
        SELECT     
        #BulkInsertTempTable.column1,
        #BulkInsertTempTable.column2,
        'defaultvalue' FROM #BulkInsertTempTable'

    EXEC (@BulkInsertSql);
```

Comment: I have execute Bulk insert query directly into table.And this my query 
BULK INSERT #Table FROM 'C:\Data\ice.dat' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR='\n',FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000).

Comment: It will perform insertion but my 6th column of the first row which having all value of second row value

Comment: can you please share your file to my email id which is there in my profile.  I  doubt about your file format.

Comment: I created sample .dat file with the 2 records you sent and executed the commands, it perfectly works for me.  As you didn't share the complete .dat file,  I can't really figure out the issue.